# Measure with uncountable union of sets

Tags: measure-theory

I have a question about one of the properties included in the measure definition:

$\mu(\cup_{k=1}^\infty E_k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(E_k)$, with $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ being pairwise disjoint sets.

If we replace this condition with:

$\mu(\cup_{\alpha \in A} E_{\alpha})=\sum_{\alpha \in A} \mu(E_{\alpha})$, where $A$ is some uncountable set of indicators.

Then is it possible that the whole power set of $\mathbb{R}$: $P(\mathbb{R})$ could be measurable (we should also change the condition in the $\sigma$-algebra definition)? Is it even possible to define the right side of the new condition (uncountable sum)?

Comment: http://www.jld-stats.com/2019/01/29/uncountably-additive-measures/

Comment: Thanks! This helps me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear to me whether you're talking about Lebesgue measure or an arbitrary measure.

### Lebesgue Measure on $\Bbb R.$

Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R$ is not uncountably additive. Say $S_x=\{x\}$. Then $\bigcup_xS_x=\Bbb R$, but $$\sum_xm(S_x)=0\ne\infty=m(\Bbb R).$$

### On the Other Hand,

let $\mu$ be counting measure on $\Bbb R$. Then $\mu$ is defined on the entire power set, and it's easy to see that it's additive for disjoint unions of any cardinality.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I meant any measure, but now I understand that it is impossible to create Lebesgue-like measure, which would hold the uncountable additive property, because of your example above and the fact that m({a}) = m([a, a]) = a - a = 0. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Yes or no, depending on exactly what you mean by "Lebesgue-like". Yes, if $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for all $x$ and $\mu(\Bbb R)>0$ then $\mu$ is sufficiently Lebesgue-like to be a counterexample...

Answer (score -1):

Let us define $\mu:\mathscr{E} \to [0,+\infty]$ where $\mathscr{E} \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$.

Recalling the following:

**Lemma:** If $(a_i)_{i \in I} \subset [0,+\infty[$ and $\sum_{i \in I} a_i < +\infty$ then only a many countable $a_i$ are strictly positive.

We observe that there is something that does not work, in general, if we assume $\mu(\cup_{\alpha \in A} E_{\alpha})=\sum_{\alpha \in A} \mu(E_{\alpha})$ for any $A$ with arbitrary cardinality.

Whenever $\mu(\cup_{\alpha \in A} E_{\alpha}) < +\infty$ then only many countable of $E_{\alpha}$ could have positive measure. This can in general produce contradictions.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I tried to edit the answer to explain what I would like to point out. Thank you for the remark.

Comment: "can in general produce contradictions"??? Why not simply _give_ one of those contradictions?